# How can I kill a child process using LUA?

Tags: lua, telegram

I'm trying to kill a process using Lua: my bash script "run.sh" prints a string each 2 seconds and up to now I was able to catch real-time the output but I need to quit that process too whenever i send a command to my telegram bot

Here is my actual code:

```
local bot, extension = require("lua-bot-api").configure('myBotToken')

local function test()
    local pipe = io.popen'/home/ubuntu/workspace/LmBot/run.sh'
        repeat
            local c = pipe:read("*line")
            if c then
                io.write(c)
                io.flush()
                bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id,c,"Markdown")
            end
        until not c
    pipe:close()
end

extension.onTextReceive = function(msg)

    local matches = {msg.text:match('^/(.+)$')}

    if(matches[1]=='start')then
        test()
    end
end

extension.run()
```

As you can see, when I send command /start it runs my bash script (is that a child process? am I right?) and sends me back a message with the output parsed by lines in real time. 
I now need to be able to kill the process started before, are there any ways using lua?

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: Have you looked at using lua-subprocess http://luaforge.net/docman/539/5782/subprocess.html and just doing it explicitly? That may be the easiest approach.

Comment: i tried but fails to install the rock. keeps printing this:

`Error: Could not find expected file sys/syscall.h for SYS_SYSCALL -- you may have to install SYS_SYSCALL in your system and/or pass SYS_SYSCALL_DIR or SYS_SYSCALL_INCDIR to the luarocks command. Example: luarocks install subprocess SYS_SYSCALL_DIR=/usr/local`

Comment: Check out [luaposix](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix). You should be able to fork a subprocess and kill it using standard POSIX calls.

Comment: A7X. It can't find syscall.h. There is no way your system doesn't have it installed, you just need to specify it's location. Use `find /usr -name syscall.h` to find it's location (there are probably multiple locations). Then pass that to luarocks with `luarocks install subprocess SYS_SYSCALL_DIR=**dir here**` If you are on a modern Ubuntu with an x86_64 processor it's probably in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/.